# Non-interactive iframe or similar solution

Tags: php, html, iframe, printscreen, non-interactive

I do websites. My clients log in and they see 5 ideas of their site design - different layout, colors etc.

Now I show them just 5 printscreens, done by me and uploaded by me. Each img links to different under-construction website.

What I want is to eliminate the need to change printscreens manually every time I change something.

I tried iFrame solution, but they are interactive.

Do you have any ideas what's the best approach?

---

EDIT:

I have (workaround) solution, but only for Chrome.

```
<a target="_parent" href="http://url.com">
<div>
<iframe id="iframe" src="http://url.com" width="300px" height="300"></iframe>
</div>
</a>
```

and some CSS to zoom out and make website look like thumbnail:

```
#iframe{
zoom: 4.0;
-moz-transform: scale(0.25);
-moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
-o-transform: scale(0.25);
-o-transform-origin: 0 0;
-webkit-transform: scale(0.25);
-webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

Chrome = size is perfect, when you click on link inside iframe browser opens my href (so much logic...), when you click inside iframe but not on a link nothing happens.

FF = thumbnail 4 times smaller than on  Chrome

IE = thumbnail 4 times larger

Comment: list all 5 images on the site at once?

Comment: yes, but it's not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You could insert a div-container, which covers the whole page, so your Users can't click anything, but on the div.

```
<div style="position:fixed;width:100%;height:100%;"></div>
```

Full code might look like this:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div style="position:fixed;width:100%;height:100%;"></div>
        <iframe src="http://www.http://stackoverflow.com" width="100%" height="300" ></iframe>
   </body>
</html>
```

EDIT: 
You can try to do this:

```
    <div id="myiframes">
        <div style="position: relative; width: 300px; height: 300px; display: inline-block;"></div>
        <iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com" width="300px" height="300" style="margin-left:-300px;"></iframe>
        <div style="position: relative; width: 300px; height: 300px;display:inline-block;"></div>
        <iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com" width="300px" height="300" style="margin-left:-300px;"></iframe>
</div>
```

Basically move each iframe beyond the div, by adding a margin of -300px; to each iframe. Change to your needs

Comment: Problem is I want rest of the page interactive. I've tried to cover only iframe with div, but with no luck.

Comment: Doesn't work. iframe is more important for some reason. Div onclick = some JS doesn't work either.